# No found error-libtensorflow framework.so.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to run one git repo on Google cloud. But the system could not find the library path.

```
myname@cloudshell:~/text-to-text-transfer-transformer (lastproject-258210)$ python3 -c "import t5; print(t5.data.MixtureRegistry.names())"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myname/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/t5/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import t5.data
  File "/home/name/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/t5/data/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import t5.data.mixtures
  File "/home/myname/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/t5/data/mixtures.py", line 26, in <module>
    import t5.data.tasks  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/myname/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/t5/data/tasks.py", line 25, in <module>
    from t5.data.utils import set_global_cache_dirs
  File "/home/myname/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/t5/data/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from t5.data import sentencepiece_vocabulary
  File "/home/myname/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/t5/data/sentencepiece_vocabulary.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tensorflow_text as tf_text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_text-1.15.0rc0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tensorflow_text/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow_text.python import metrics
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_text-1.15.0rc0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow_text.python.metrics.text_similarity_metric_ops import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_text-1.15.0rc0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/text_similarity_metric_ops.py", line 28, in <module>
    gen_text_similarity_metric_ops = load_library.load_op_library(resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile('_text_similarity_metric_ops.so'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libtensorflow_framework.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to print out the location of the libtensorflow:

```
 myname@cloudshell:~/text-to-text-transfer-transformer (lastproject-258210)$ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())'
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core
```

The question is how could I change the path so the system will find the path.Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What is the output of running this `tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()`??

Comment: Did you try set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory with the library?

Comment: @Anwarvic Thanks for your reply! After running this command, it returns nothing

Comment: @data, I think this is the problem... what is your `tensorflow` version??

Comment: @Anwarvic tensorflow==1.15.0. I am trying to run this repo.https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/master/README.md See in the middle of the text-the Ctpu up part, they use 1.15.0 version

Comment: I'm sorry, you mean `1.14`??

Comment: @pawols thanks for ur help! I am checking now

Comment: @Anwarvic In the README on that repo, they requested --tf-version=1.15.dev20190821. But I have a version like 1.15.0. Because with their arg, I can't get Ctpu Up run

Comment: @data, I didn't know there was `1.15` version.. but you're right according to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf).

Comment: @Anwarvic yes, they use 1.15.

Comment: my suggestion is to re-install `tensorflow` or install lower version. According to this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27430), people recommend installing `tensorflow=1.13`

Comment: @pawols Do you mean something like this? export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core and set in the bash file?

Comment: @Anwarvic I could try. Not sure though. :)

Comment: @data Yes, I mean something like that. You have to check if in this directory is your *.so lib

Comment: @data Does it work?

Comment: @pawols Nope. I tried both echo 'export that path to/' >> ~/.bashrc as well as add the path under the /root/.bashc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the tensorflow-text version specified in the pip package (1.15rc0), which matches tensorflow 1.15.0. Are you manually installing a different version?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply. Yes, I had to install many modules manually. It would be very nice if  the requirements.txt file is available. I can run ctpu up command easily but with the command ctpu up --name=$TPU_NAME --project=$PROJECT --zone=$ZONE --tpu-size=v3-8 \ --tpu-only --tf-version=1.15.dev20190821 --noconf, I just can't get it through. Even manually installed everything, there are lots of errors to be solved. e.g. allennlp. Here are some details of what I have tried for the first 2-3 steps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7puYh9DVkYrU6f-sReFkCcNVuIA_vFc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should be able to start from scratch with `pip install t5[gcp]` and get the correct versions. What issue are you hitting when you do that?

Comment: The problem was not with pip install. The problem happens when using "ctpu...---nonconf" command even though all the permissions were given, instance and storage were set. Error messages change from time to time. e.g. permission issues or the last one was flock name "" is not a valid flock name (must be at least 2 characters). Note: using only " ctpu up --name=$TPU_NAME --project=$PROJECT --zone=$ZONE" command works fine. But then I don't have other parameters